# Both key column and map-key are PK

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

How do I create a map property that has both key column and a map key as parts of PK of the detail class?

Like this:

```
<class entity-name="Person"  >
    <id name="id"/>
    <property name="birthDate" type="date"/>
    <map name="names">
        <key column="personId"/>
        <map-key type="string" column="code"/>
        <one-to-many class="PersonName" />
    </map>
</class>


<class entity-name="PersonName">
    <composite-id>
        <key-many-to-one name="personId" class="Person"/>
        <key-property name="code" type="string" length="32"/>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="lastName" type="string" length="64" index="nameSearch"/>
    <property name="firstName" type="string" length="64" index="nameSearch"/>
    <property name="middleName" type="string" length="64" index="nameSearch"/>
    <property name="isActual" type="boolean"/>
</class>
```

I need to avoid creating a surrogate key in PersonName class that would require a special handling. Json shown below should be automatically persisted in the DB, inserting and updating detail record when necessary, based on PersonId-code key.

It's natural that "code" property identifies the row together with the person Id.

I tried different combinations of "inverse", "not-null" etc. I admit that I don't fully get how it works. I get different error messages, like:

> ERROR: null value in "person" column violates NOT NULL constraint
>   Details: Erroreous row contains (null, null, lastname, ffffirst, null, null).

or:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: 
>   PersonName column: person (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

It should look like this, if represented as json:

```
{
    "birthDate": "33-44-55",
    "names": {
        "mainName": {
            "lastName": "lastname",
            "firstName": "ffffirst"
        },
        "maidenName": {
            "lastName": "lastname1",
            "firstName": "ffffirst2"
        },
        "old": {
            "lastName": "lastname3",
            "firstName": "ffffirst4"
        }

    }
}
```

**UPD (clarification of question)**
Actually this is a main goal - the system should create master and all details when posted with this json. This json is converted into the mapped classes. If master has an "id" populated, the system should update both master and details, adding new entries when needed. Details ("names" map entries) should not have any surrogate "id" specified. They are identified by master's "personId" field and "code" field.

** clarification 2 **
As shown in the example json, the map key is a string, not a composite key. As seen in mapping xml, this is all dynamic mapping. No additional class, that couldn't be instantiated automatically from the json, should be written.

Hope it's possible!

To get the whole picture, the table is generated OK, I like it:

```
CREATE TABLE personname
(
  personid character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  code character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  lastname character varying(64),
  firstname character varying(64),
  middlename character varying(64),
  isactual boolean,
  CONSTRAINT personname_pkey PRIMARY KEY (personid, code),
  CONSTRAINT fk_1skg5frawyftx8co9uawhc3r8 FOREIGN KEY (personid)
      REFERENCES person (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Comment: Dear all, I would accept the answer that hibernate is unable to help me to achieve what I want. It has many features, including the ability to specify the map key, but this feature doesn't mean that in the detail table it will be restricted to have multiple entries for one map key. Map key has just ornamental meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible. Use mongodb or write your own ORM.

Comment: It's possible, but not with your current domain model. For every Json map you need an association table. The question is: is it worth? Maybe a json storage is what you need anyway.

Comment: It means something else is possible, but not what I was asking. In a "names" map definition, key column and map key should point to a PK of other table. Not that a map key should consist of two fields, sorry. Yes it is the best model for maps of details one can think of. If map key is not part of PK, two values could be mapped to one map key, which is just wrong. What hibernate authors were thinking about when they introduced a good concept of map key but with a flaw?

Comment: Yes, ORM is tricky and JSON is not strictly supported. I hope you find your answer with Hibernate, but if you're willing to go to something more specific I'd suggest Postgres Hstore or MongoDb.

Answer (score 2):

I think your mapping should look like this:

You need a nested Key class (e.g. Person$Key, although it can be an outer class too) for the embedded composite id:

```
public static class Key {
    private Long personId;
    private String code;

    public Key(Long personId, String code) {
        this.personId = personId;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Long getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Key)) {
            return false;
        }
        Key k = (Key)obj;
        return personId.equals(k.personId) && code.equals(k.code);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 37*personId.hashCode() + code.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Then your map will be like:

```
private Map<Key,PersonName> names = new HashMap<Key,PersonName>();
```

The Hibernate mapping:

```
<class entity-name="Person"  >
     <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="birthDate" type="date"/>
    <map name="names" inverse="true">
        <composite-map-key class="Person$Key">
            <key-property name="personId"/>
            <key-property name="code"/>
        </composite-map-key>
        <one-to-many class="PersonName" />
    </map>
</class>

<class entity-name="PersonName">
    <composite-id name="id" class="Person">
        <key-property name="personId"/>
        <key-property name="code"/>
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one name="person" class="Person"
        insert="false" update="false">
        <column name="personId"/>
        <column name="code"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="lastName" type="string" length="64" index="nameSearch"/>
    <property name="firstName" type="string" length="64" index="nameSearch"/>
    <property name="middleName" type="string" length="64" index="nameSearch"/>
    <property name="isActual" type="boolean"/>
</class>
```

Comment: seems i will lose the ability to have multiple PersonNames for one Person. trying to upderstand your advice or modify the solution with the composite key...

Comment: You can have multiple PersonNames for a Person, it's a one to many mapping.

Comment: Would the PersonNames of one Person have the same value in the personId field?

Comment: I updated my example so that both a Person and a PersonName have synthetic ids, and so you can have more PersonNames for the same Person.

Comment: Thanks, though this is not what I wanted. I wanted to avoid surrogate id in PersonName. The Person Name should uniquely identified by Person id and the "code". I am not against of having a special id in a PersonName, but I don't want it to appear in any of the jsons and make client to store and keep track of this id and its correspondence to person and code.

Comment: Is it a typo - '<one-to-many class="person" />'? did you mean <one-to-many class="PersonName" />?
It also told me "Attribute "class" is required and must be specified for element type "composite-map-key"", as well as made me to precede this with <key> element.

Anyway, it says "Class not found" whatever I put there.
Didn't know it matters, but it is all "dymanic mapping" as described here

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch04.html#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels

now I'm struggling to make it work playing with "class", "entity-name" and other parameters.

Comment: Yes, I misspelled that. It may be that you have to provide a wrapper class for the composite key, like an Embeddable.

Comment: The only reason I'm trying to use hibernate is dynamic model. The idea is not to write any classes... I will try a little more later this week.

Comment: The composite-map-key requires a class for holding a key, which makes sense since it's a container for the java.util.Map key. I updated the example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Haven't yet tried, but would such a solution let me get a name of a person by a code, like this: aPerson.get("names").get("maidenName") as in the json I mentioned in my question? Seems like not and I will have to create a Key instance, will I?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56702/discussion-between-vlad-mihalcea-and-fedd).

Comment: Thanks. For general public I would still stress what I need: "the system should create master and all details when posted with this json. " if hibernate is unable to do that I would rather choose mongodb. I still hope that hibernate was written to simplify usage of rdbms.

Comment: Sorry I can't accept this as an answer. The map key should be a string, it's implied by my json example and now I stated this explicitly